# Finding components at a specific location on a JDialog that used GridBagLayout

Tags: java, gridbaglayout, jdialog

I have a JDialog with rows of components created dynamically using GridBagLayout. I position the components using a method I found on this forum.

```
 public static GridBagConstraints makeGbc(int x, int y) {
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      Insets WEST_INSETS=new Insets(5,0,5,5);
      Insets EAST_INSETS=new Insets(5,5,5,0);
      gbc.gridx = x;
      gbc.gridy = y;
      gbc.gridwidth = 1;
      gbc.gridheight = 1;

      gbc.anchor = (x == 0) ? GridBagConstraints.WEST : GridBagConstraints.EAST;
      gbc.fill = (x == 0) ? GridBagConstraints.BOTH
            : GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

      gbc.insets = (x == 0) ? WEST_INSETS : EAST_INSETS;
      gbc.weightx = (x == 0) ? 0.1 : 1.0;
      gbc.weighty = 1.0;
      return gbc;
   }
```

This makes it easy to specify a row and column for each component and it works perfectly.

I now would now like to write a method that will return whatever component exists at a corresponding row and column. Is this possible and if so how would I accomplish it? TIA.

This is not a duplicate as I know the location I want to check but I don't know what component is there. I need to pass the x,y coordinates and return the component. I know I have to build a method but I don't see off hand how to do it.